Dask Read SQL error "String data right truncation"
I am trying to read a DB2 Z/OS database using dask (replacing pandas).
Testing with pandas
query = f'''
WITH tags_amazon AS
(
select distinct 
    t1.CD_REF_CNV,
    t1.CD_CLI
from DB2I023A.espl_ref_cnv_cbac t1
where t1.CD_LOJA in ('62e29b1a5e2e9d94534b6aa4', '6061f9fd5c11ec345b3d9a94')
),
amazon_orders AS 
(
SELECT t1.NM_VNDR,
    t1.CD_REF_CNV,
    t1.DT_CPR,
    t1.NM_CTGR_CPR,
    (t1.QT_PRD * t1.VL_CPR) as gmv,
    t2.CD_CLI
 from DB2I023A.espl_cnv_cbac t1
    inner join tags_amazon t2
        on (t1.CD_REF_CNV = t2.CD_REF_CNV)
where t1.DT_CPR BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31'
)
SELECT t3.* 
FROM amazon_orders t3;'''
df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con='ibm_db_sa://XXX:XXX@gXXX:XXX/XXX', index_col = 'cd_ref_cnv' )


And i get the expected result.
Now, same query just replacing pandas as dask.
df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con='ibm_db_sa://XXX:XXX@gXXX:XXX/XXX', index_col = 'cd_ref_cnv' )

And I get this weird error.
DataError: (ibm_db_dbi.DataError) ibm_db_dbi::DataError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0109E  String data right truncation. SQLSTATE=22001 SQLCODE=-99999
[SQL: SELECT "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."NAME", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."TYPENAME", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."DEFAULT", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."NULLS", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."LENGTH", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."SCALE", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."GENERATED_ATTR", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."REMARKS" 
FROM "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS" 
WHERE "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."TBCREATOR" = ? AND "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."TBNAME" = ? ORDER BY "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."COLNO"]
[parameters: ('DB2I023A', "\n    WITH tags_amazon AS\n    (\n    select distinct \n    \tt1.CD_REF_CNV,\n    \tt1.CD_CLI\n    from DB2I023A.espl_ref_cnv_cbac t1\n    where t1.C ... (327 characters truncated) ...  \ton (t1.CD_REF_CNV = t2.CD_REF_CNV)\n    where t1.DT_CPR BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31'\n    )\n    SELECT t3.* \n    FROM amazon_orders t3;")]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/9h9h)

Any tips where to start?
As suggested, including the full error output. I´ve never seem such a big error on dask/pandas/python!:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last) File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py:1312, in Cursor._execute_helper(self, parameters)    1311 try:
-> 1312     return_value = ibm_db.execute(self.stmt_handler, parameters)    1313     if not return_value:

Exception: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0109E  String data right truncation. SQLSTATE=22001 SQLCODE=-99999

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1960, in Connection._exec_single_context(self, dialect, context, statement, parameters)    1959     if not evt_handled:
-> 1960         self.dialect.do_execute(    1961             cursor, str_statement, effective_parameters, context    1962         )    1964 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/ibm_db.py:138, in DB2Dialect_ibm_db.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    137 else:
--> 138     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py:1409, in Cursor.execute(self, operation, parameters)    1408 self._prepare_helper(operation)
-> 1409 self._execute_helper(parameters)    1410 self._set_cursor_helper()

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py:1322, in Cursor._execute_helper(self, parameters)    1321         self.messages.append(_get_exception(inst))
-> 1322         raise self.messages[len(self.messages) - 1]    1323 else:

DataError: ibm_db_dbi::DataError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0109E  String data right truncation. SQLSTATE=22001 SQLCODE=-99999

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[9], line 2
      1 datainicio,datafim = datas_atualização('Recargas')
----> 2 db_recargas = db_recargas_gmv(engine = enginedb2.uri, dtinicio = datainicio, dtfim= datafim)

Cell In[7], line 25, in db_recargas_gmv(engine, dtinicio, dtfim)
      2 def db_recargas_gmv (engine, dtinicio, dtfim):
      3     query = F'''
      4     WITH temp1 AS
      5         (    (...)
     23     FROM unificado;
     24     '''
---> 25     df = dd.read_sql(sql=query, con=engine, index_col = 'CONVENIO' )
     26     df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)
     27     df = df.astype({'CONVENIO':'Int32', 'DATA' : 'datetime64[ns]', 'GMV' : 'Float64', 'receita' : 'Float64',  'MCI' : 'Int32' })

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py:393, in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, **kwargs)
    360 """
    361 Read SQL query or database table into a DataFrame.
    362     (...)
    390 read_sql_query : Read SQL query into a DataFrame.
    391 """
    392 if isinstance(sql, str):
--> 393     return read_sql_table(sql, con, index_col, **kwargs)
    394 else:
    395     return read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, **kwargs)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py:314, in read_sql_table(table_name, con, index_col, divisions, npartitions, limits, columns, bytes_per_chunk, head_rows, schema, meta, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
    312 m = sa.MetaData()
    313 if isinstance(table_name, str):
--> 314     table_name = sa.Table(table_name, m, autoload_with=engine, schema=schema)
    315 else:
    316     raise TypeError(
    317         "`table_name` must be of type str, not " + str(type(table_name))
    318     )

File <string>:2, in __new__(cls, *args, **kw)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py:281, in deprecated_params.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.warned(fn, *args,
**kwargs)
    274     if m in kwargs:
    275         _warn_with_version(
    276             messages[m],
    277             versions[m],
    278             version_warnings[m],
    279             stacklevel=3,
    280         )
--> 281 return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py:431, in Table.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
    424 @util.deprecated_params(
    425     mustexist=(
    426         "1.4",    (...)
    429 )
    430 def __new__(cls, *args: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
--> 431     return cls._new(*args, **kw)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py:485, in Table._new(cls, *args, **kw)
    483     return table
    484 except Exception:
--> 485     with util.safe_reraise():
    486         metadata._remove_table(name, schema)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:146, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
    144     assert exc_value is not None
    145     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
--> 146     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
    147 else:
    148     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py:481, in Table._new(cls, *args, **kw)
    479 metadata._add_table(name, schema, table)
    480 try:
--> 481     table.__init__(name, metadata, *args, _no_init=False, **kw)
    482     table.dispatch.after_parent_attach(table, metadata)
    483     return table

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py:861, in Table.__init__(self, name, metadata, schema, quote, quote_schema, autoload_with, autoload_replace, keep_existing, extend_existing, resolve_fks, include_columns, implicit_returning, comment, info, listeners, prefixes, _extend_on, _no_init, *args, **kw)
    857 # load column definitions from the database if 'autoload' is defined
    858 # we do it after the table is in the singleton dictionary to support
    859 # circular foreign keys
    860 if autoload_with is not None:
--> 861     self._autoload(
    862         metadata,
    863         autoload_with,
    864         include_columns,
    865         _extend_on=_extend_on,
    866         _reflect_info=_reflect_info,
    867         resolve_fks=resolve_fks,
    868     )
    870 # initialize all the column, etc. objects.  done after reflection to
    871 # allow user-overrides
    873 self._init_items(
    874     *args,
    875     allow_replacements=extend_existing    (...)
    878     all_names={},
    879 )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py:893, in Table._autoload(self, metadata, autoload_with, include_columns, exclude_columns, resolve_fks, _extend_on, _reflect_info)
    891 insp = inspection.inspect(autoload_with)
    892 with insp._inspection_context() as conn_insp:
--> 893     conn_insp.reflect_table(
    894         self,
    895         include_columns,
    896         exclude_columns,
    897         resolve_fks,
    898         _extend_on=_extend_on,
    899         _reflect_info=_reflect_info,
    900     )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py:1526, in Inspector.reflect_table(self, table, include_columns, exclude_columns, resolve_fks, _extend_on, _reflect_info)    1524 table_key = (schema, table_name)    1525 if _reflect_info is None or table_key not in _reflect_info.columns:
-> 1526     _reflect_info = self._get_reflection_info(    1527         schema,    1528         filter_names=[table_name],    1529         kind=ObjectKind.ANY,    1530         scope=ObjectScope.ANY,    1531   
_reflect_info=_reflect_info,    1532         **table.dialect_kwargs,    1533     )    1534 if table_key in _reflect_info.unreflectable:    1535     raise _reflect_info.unreflectable[table_key]

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py:2006, in Inspector._get_reflection_info(self, schema, filter_names, available, _reflect_info, **kw)    2002         res = {}    2003     return res    2005 info = _ReflectionInfo(
-> 2006     columns=run(    2007         self.get_multi_columns, check_filter_names_from_meth=True    2008     ),    2009     pk_constraint=run(self.get_multi_pk_constraint),    2010     foreign_keys=run(self.get_multi_foreign_keys),    2011     indexes=run(self.get_multi_indexes),    2012     unique_constraints=run(    2013         self.get_multi_unique_constraints, optional=True    2014     ),    2015     table_comment=run(self.get_multi_table_comment, optional=True),    2016     check_constraints=run(    2017         self.get_multi_check_constraints, optional=True    2018     ),    2019 table_options=run(self.get_multi_table_options, optional=True),    2020     unreflectable=unreflectable,    2021 )    2022 if
_reflect_info:    2023     _reflect_info.update(info)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py:1992, in Inspector._get_reflection_info.<locals>.run(meth, optional, check_filter_names_from_meth)    1990 try:    1991     if has_result:
-> 1992         res = meth(filter_names=_fn, **kw)    1993         if check_filter_names_from_meth and not res:    1994             # method returned no result data.    1995             # skip any future call methods    1996             has_result = False

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py:921, in Inspector.get_multi_columns(self, schema, filter_names, kind, scope, **kw)
    884 r"""Return information about columns in all objects in the given
    885 schema.
    886     (...)
    917 .. seealso:: :meth:`Inspector.get_columns`
    918 """
    920 with self._operation_context() as conn:
--> 921     table_col_defs = dict(
    922         self.dialect.get_multi_columns(
    923             conn,
    924             schema=schema,
    925             filter_names=filter_names,
    926             kind=kind,
    927             scope=scope,
    928             info_cache=self.info_cache,
    929             **kw,
    930         )
    931     )
    932 self._instantiate_types(table_col_defs.values())
    933 return table_col_defs

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:1101, in DefaultDialect._default_multi_reflect(self, single_tbl_method, connection, kind, schema, filter_names, scope, **kw)    1097 key = (schema, table)    1098 try:    1099     yield (    1100         key,
-> 1101         single_tbl_method(    1102             connection, table, schema=schema, **kw    1103         ),    1104     )    1105 except exc.UnreflectableTableError as err:    1106     if key not in unreflectable:

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/base.py:734, in DB2Dialect.get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema, **kw)
    733 def get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema=None, **kw):
--> 734     return self._reflector.get_columns(connection, table_name, schema=schema, **kw)

File <string>:2, in get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema,
**kw)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py:97, in cache(fn, self, con, *args, **kw)
     95 ret: _R = info_cache.get(key)
     96 if ret is None:
---> 97     ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
     98     info_cache[key] = ret
     99 return ret

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/reflection.py:983, in OS390Reflector.get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema,
**kw)
    974 query = sql.select(syscols.c.colname, syscols.c.typename,
    975                    syscols.c.defaultval, syscols.c.nullable,
    976                    syscols.c.length, syscols.c.scale,    (...)
    980         syscols.c.tabname == table_name)).\
    981     order_by(syscols.c.colno)
    982 sa_columns = []
--> 983 for r in connection.execute(query):
    984     coltype = r[1].upper()
    985     if coltype in ['DECIMAL', 'NUMERIC']:

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1408, in Connection.execute(self, statement, parameters, execution_options)  1406     raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(statement) from err    1407 else:
-> 1408     return meth(    1409         self,    1410         distilled_parameters,    1411         execution_options or NO_OPTIONS, 1412     )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:513, in ClauseElement._execute_on_connection(self, connection, distilled_params, execution_options)
    511     if TYPE_CHECKING:
    512         assert isinstance(self, Executable)
--> 513     return connection._execute_clauseelement(
    514         self, distilled_params, execution_options
    515     )
    516 else:
    517     raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1630, in Connection._execute_clauseelement(self, elem, distilled_parameters, execution_options)    1618 compiled_cache: Optional[CompiledCacheType]
= execution_options.get(    1619     "compiled_cache", self.engine._compiled_cache    1620 )    1622 compiled_sql, extracted_params, cache_hit = elem._compile_w_cache(    1623     dialect=dialect,    1624     compiled_cache=compiled_cache,    (...)   1628     linting=self.dialect.compiler_linting | compiler.WARN_LINTING,    1629 )
-> 1630 ret = self._execute_context(    1631     dialect,    1632     dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_compiled,    1633     compiled_sql,    1634     distilled_parameters,    1635     execution_options,    1636  compiled_sql,    1637     distilled_parameters,    1638     elem,    1639     extracted_params,    1640     cache_hit=cache_hit,    1641 )  1642 if has_events:    1643     self.dispatch.after_execute(    1644   self,    1645         elem,    (...)    1649         ret,    1650     )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1839, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)    1834     return self._exec_insertmany_context(    1835         dialect,    1836        context,    1837     )    1838 else:
-> 1839     return self._exec_single_context(    1840         dialect, context, statement, parameters    1841     )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1979, in Connection._exec_single_context(self, dialect, context, statement, parameters)    1976     result = context._setup_result_proxy()    1978 except BaseException as e:
-> 1979     self._handle_dbapi_exception(    1980         e, str_statement, effective_parameters, cursor, context    1981     )    1983 return result

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2335, in Connection._handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context, is_sub_exec)    2333 elif should_wrap:    2334     assert sqlalchemy_exception is not None
-> 2335     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e    2336 else:    2337     assert exc_info[1] is not None

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1960, in Connection._exec_single_context(self, dialect, context, statement, parameters)    1958                 break    1959     if not evt_handled:
-> 1960         self.dialect.do_execute(    1961             cursor, str_statement, effective_parameters, context    1962         )    1964 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:    1965     self.dispatch.after_cursor_execute(    1966         self,    1967      cursor,    (...)    1971         context.executemany,    1972     )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/ibm_db.py:138, in DB2Dialect_ibm_db.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    136     context._callproc_result = cursor.callproc(statement, parameters)
    137 else:
--> 138     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py:1409, in Cursor.execute(self, operation, parameters)    1407 self._all_stmt_handlers = []    1408 self._prepare_helper(operation)
-> 1409 self._execute_helper(parameters)    1410 self._set_cursor_helper()    1411 return self._set_rowcount()

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py:1322, in Cursor._execute_helper(self, parameters)    1320     except Exception as inst:    1321         self.messages.append(_get_exception(inst))
-> 1322         raise self.messages[len(self.messages) - 1]    1323 else:    1324     try:

DataError: (ibm_db_dbi.DataError) ibm_db_dbi::DataError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0109E  String data right truncation. SQLSTATE=22001 SQLCODE=-99999 [SQL: SELECT "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."NAME", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."TYPENAME", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."DEFAULT", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."NULLS", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."LENGTH", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."SCALE", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."GENERATED_ATTR", "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."REMARKS"  FROM "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"  WHERE "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."TBCREATOR" = ? AND "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."TBNAME" = ? ORDER BY "SYSIBM"."SYSCOLUMNS"."COLNO"] [parameters: ('DB2I023A', "\n    WITH temp1 AS\n\t\t(\n\t\tselect *\n\t\tfrom DB2I023A.RECARGAS_GMV_AJUSTADO t1\n        where  t1.DATA BETWEEN '2024-04-14' AND '2024-04-28'\n\ ... (173 characters truncated) ... \n       unificado AS \n       (\n\t\tSELECT * FROM temp1\n    \t\tUNION ALL\n\t\tSELECT * FROM temp2\n       )\n\tSELECT * \n\tFROM unificado;\n    ")] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/9h9h)


Time for some debugging...if you edit your question to show the full backtrace (as plain text), you might get more advice. Otherwise, use a trace from clidriver (refer to the IBM Db2-LUW knowledge center for help on using the db2trc command to enable tracing, to dump the trace output, and then convert the dumped output into text readable files. If that is too difficult for you, then open a ticket with the provider of the dask library. However, you may need to provide a minimal reproducible scenario for others to recreate.

I´ve included the full error ouput.

Please edit your question to add the text output of pip list.  The exception appears SQLAlchemy reflection.py in OS390Reflector, but I don't know why pandas/dask should cause behaviour differences here. Are there any "remarks on column" for any of the columns mentioned in your query? Are any of the columns generated? A useful (temporary) elimination would be to see if the Db2-LUW reflection has the same problem because if so, then it is a lot easier to debug than on Db2-for-Z/OS, hence my suggestion that you make a standalone minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the problem.
